# Spreadsheet sent to me that references an .xlam file on her desktop, how do i make it work for me?

Tags: excel, add-in, vba

A colleague sent me a spreadsheet she uses to forecast days of coverage for a raw material.  It was created by someone who is now retired, so we don't have a point of reference.

The calculation in a column of cells in the spreadsheet she sent me looks like this:

='C:\Users\username\Desktop\Forward IDS 20121114.xlam'!forwardIDS(1,F2193/0.65,E2194,E2195,E2196..)

So this function seems to read the macro at this file location, then it does a calculation with the cells in the current spreadsheet (the E# cells represent production amounts).

When I add my values to column E, it completely breaks the function, and I get a "#NAME?" error in all the cells that reference the desktop file location.  I tried to save this .xlam file referenced to my desktop, then switched her username with mine, but I get the same error.

I am not really sure what the reference to this .xlam file is doing, I just need it to do the same calculations on my spreadsheet.  I can find the VBA code for the Add-in via VBE, and I was even able to disable the Add-in property so I can see the underlying spreadsheet used.  Maybe there is a way I can just create my own version of this with all of that information available to me?

Answer (score 0):

She has created a custom function "ForwardIDS" that is stored inside that .xlam. You will have to either: A) Copy the .xlam to your computer or B) Copy the custom function into the workbook's code module.
Once you've done that you will need to update any cells that reference that function and point them to the correct location.
If you move the function to the workbook's code module you can change those formulas to just read: `=forwardIDS(1,F2193/0.65,E2194,E2195,E2196..)`

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I copied the macro code into the workbook, but when I remove the file location, and set it up as starting from "Forward IDS".  I receive a "Compile Error - Can't find Project or Library".  The .XLAM file actually has a table in it on a spreadsheet.  I think this means I will have to point the code to a copy of the file on my desktop rather than just copying the VBA code